# How can I upgrade the react-native version?

Tags: react-native, upgrade

I tried to update my react-native version to latest one. i.e react-native 0.60.3
I got the following error with these two methods.

````
C:\Users\Kamlesh\Desktop\Final Project>react-native upgrade

info No version passed. Fetching latest...
info Fetching diff between v0.59.9 and v0.60.4...
error Failed to fetch diff for react-native@0.60.4. Maybe it's not released yet?
info For available releases to diff see: https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge#version-changes```


C:\Users\Kamlesh\Desktop\Final Project>react-native upgrade react-native@0.60.3

info Fetching diff between v0.59.9 and v0.60.3...
error Failed to fetch diff for react-native@0.60.3. Maybe it's not released yet?
info For available releases to diff see: https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge#version-changes
````

Comment: You should make sure that you are using the most recent version of the `@react-native-community/cli`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. How do I fixed?

- change package.json setting react-native to 0.59.10
- run `npm install`
- now run `react-native upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution:
Simply list all the packages which needs to be updated and get all the packages with the latest version.
Use the following using npm.

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```